# Larevel / MySQL Get latest records only with additional condition

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a hasOne relationship. The image shows the records of the relationship which have the same "contract_id"

Following result is required:

I want to only select the last record with the highest "version" => 5, but only if the "status" column is not "draft". Otherwise don't select the parent record at all if the relationship doesn't fulfill the condition. ($contract::with('latestVersion')->paginate())

I don't want to get the next possible record that fullfills the condition - meaning:

I don't want to get "version 3" with "status active"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGzZy.png)

I tried to sort by latest() or groupBy('version')...

Answer (score 0):

add to your conditions:

```
->where('status', '!=', 'draft')->orderByDesc('version')->limit(1);
```

The above will result into the single highest `version` that is not `status` `draft`

more on the topic: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-clauses & https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#ordering

Comment: This will make it select the version 3 which is not draft... It should not select it at all and only consider the information from the latest version.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I thought you already knew how to order the query :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `whereHas` or `withWhereHas` that put additional `where` conditions on your `has` queries.

```
$contract::whereHas('latestVersion', function ($query) {
    $query->where('version', '=', 5)->where('status', '!=', 'draft');
})->paginate();
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: The "5" is variable - it could be 25. Can't be hardcoded

Comment: In that case, You have to get the maximum version using separate query, isn't it?